# Node.JS Express structuring a big app

Tags: node.js, rest, express, crud

I am interested in creating a CRUD Rest API using Node.js together with express. I was wondering if their was a structuring standard of some sort or MVC framework which is used in the industry to structure my code create models etc...

I know that I should structure the different models into different npm projects but how to structure a single project is what I am looking for...

Also I am very interested in using a mediator design pattern to decrease coupling between the different modules.

Any examples/blogs/gits/books will help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did a [screencast on this topic](http://www.learnallthenodes.com/episodes/8-how-to-structure-a-node-app) in which I propose an app structure that has served me well for APIs and projects with UIs.  Do I claim this is gospel and then end-all-be-all?  No.  But it has served me well.

In short it looks something like this:

```
app_root
  app
    routes 
      - route handlers go here
    models 
      - if you use models
    commands 
      - if you use commands
    middleware 
      - middlewarez
  config
    application.js - the stuff that bootstraps your application.  Reusable in contexts other than your server (thing testing)
    routes.js - All your route mappings in one place
  test
    test_helper.js - Bootstrap your testing (require config/application.js, etc)
    models 
      - tests for your models (follow suit for other things under app)
  server.js - starts up your webserver
```

I put this empty app structure up on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bigohstudios/node_app).

Answer (score -1):

You could use Google's AngularJS + Node.JS where the angular frameworkwork separates view and controller. Look into Angular site for example and tutorial.

Comment: to be more specific i'm not interested in views/ rendering of views. As the API sole purpose is to transmit json